# Bash readline move cursor to previous forward slash

Tags: linux, bash, vi, readline

In bash , we can move back or forward by 1 word or character. Is there any option where i can move the cursor to the previous character that i specify, for example Forward Slash. ? Something like the `f` key stroke in vim which searches for the previous occurence of the following character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash's **emacs** mode:

**character-search (`C-]`)**

> A character is read and point is moved to the next occurrence of
>   that  character.   A negative count searches for previous occurrences.

**character-search-backward (`M-C-]`)**

> A character is read and point is moved to  the  previous  occurrence  of  that character.  A negative count searches for subsequent occurrences.

I'd recommend you use the **vi** mode and **f** works just like in the *vi* editor. You'll find it's very convenient for command line editing.

To switch between `vi` and `emacs` mode, use `set -o vi` or `set -o emacs`.